# R: Lag returns input

Tags: r

For example if I use `lag(c(1:10), k = 1)`, it returns  1, 2, ..., 10. How do I get this function to work at all?
I tried looking at the documentation, but whatever I've tried from there didn't work either.

Comment: What is `k = 1` supposed to be doing?  `k` is not a parameter in the `dplyr` version of `lag`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `k = 1` is a parameter of `stats::lag`

Comment: `lag(x, k)` (the "base" version from stats), requires that `x` is a time series object. Use the `dplyr` version if you want to apply the same functionality to other types of objects.

Comment: `stats::lag()` works like this: `stats::lag(ts(1:10, frequency = 4), 1)`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You already got it working, but it is not obvious from the first glance:

```
(x <- lag(1:10, k = 1))
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#attr(,"tsp")
#[1] 0 9 1
?tsp
#..The tsp attribute gives the start time in time units, the end time and the frequency
#(the number of observations per unit of time, e.g. 12 for a monthly series)...
#...See Also: ts, time, start...
?time
#...time creates the vector of times at which a time series was sampled...
time(x)
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#attr(,"tsp")
#[1] 0 9 1
as.numeric(time(x))
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Several packages offer a range of `lag` functions. Make sure that the one you apply comes from the right package. Examples below:

Using `lag` from `stats`:

```
> stats::lag(c(1:10), k = 1)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
attr(,"tsp")
[1] 0 9 1
```

This `lag` function from `stats` is intended to be applied onto a time-series object, not a numeric vector.

Using `lag` from `dplyr`:

```
> dplyr::lag(c(1:10))
 [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Comment: It seems to be clear that the OP is referring to the base version, i.e. the one provided by stats.

Comment: `stats::lag` won't work considering `c(1:10)` is not `Date` or eqv ts object.